# Is it possible to omit audit in heroku deployment?

Tags: npm, heroku, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a nextJS app using Heroku Git, but there are some vulnearbilities of some dependecies that make the build fail when deploying.
Is it possible to execute something like npm install --no-audit during heroku deployment?

Comment: You should probably fix the vulnerabilities, then the deployment would pass.

Comment: The problem is that the last version of a library I'm using (react-rainbow-components) has this vulnerability and has not fixed it yet, so while they do it, I was hoping I could skip the audit for the deployment